# Round to nearest 10 multiplication

Tags: sql, t-sql, math, formula

I have a bit of math question for my sql code. I want to be able to work out the following in my code using a mathematical formula, if anyone knows how I would love to know.

Any number 1->99      : **10**

Any number 100->999   : **100**

Any number 1000->9999 : **1000**
...

Is there anyway to work out the 10 multiplier just from the value? I feel like this should be an easy formula but I cant seem to get it.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: I think your example should be `1 -> 9 : 1` and `10 -> 99 : 10`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to set 10 if number is between 1 to 99, 100 if number is between 100 to 999 and 1000 if number is between 1000 to 9999?

Comment: It's probably something along the lines of `SELECT POWER(10, LEN(CAST(@i as int)) - 1)`, but the 1-9 part being included in 10 is confusing me

Comment: The question is pretty clear to me.  I just don't know the answer.

Comment: If you read the question a few times, it becomes clear.  That, to me, means the question should be made clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT POWER(10, CONVERT(INT, LOG10(@Input)))
```

It takes the log base 10 of the input value (which returns the value of the exponent to which you would have to raise `10` to in order to get the input value), then it lops off the decimal portion leaving only the whole number, and then raises 10 to that power.

Answer (score 3):

You just need logs and their opposite (power)...

```
power(10, floor(log10(x)))
```

As follows...

```
log10(99) = 1.9956351946

floor(1.9956351946) = 1

power(10, 1) = 10
```

This does, however, assume that your example is wrong and that `1 -> 9` should "round" to 1...

```
log10(9) = 0.95424250943

floor(0.95424250943) = 0

power(10, 0) = 1
```

Comment: You are correct I believe my example was a little wrong, this is an excellent explanation, thanks :)